# Why does Amazon sometimes say there are no customer reviews when there are?

Tags: amazon

[For example](http://www.amazon.ca/Schultz-Purpose-Plant-10-15-10-1012/dp/B001PCYJ4A); at the top it says "Be the first to review this item" but lower it says  "Amazon.com: 4.5 out of 5 stars  47 reviews". What's the deal? This is a problem because if I selected to show results from a search with more than a certain number of stars then results like this one may be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is where the reviews were written.  Amazon has multiple sites that it operates from different countries.  The link you provided was from Amazon.CA (the Canada site).  On the .CA site, there are no reviews available.  Instead, it is showing you the reviews from the main Amazon.COM site (the US site).

While these are likely to be identical products, various shipping, marketing or legal reasons may prevent you from getting an identical product when ordered and/or shipped from one country's site to a different country.  That is why they distinguish the reviews (and probably why the reviews they show are still listed as "beta").